# MUI DataGrid Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using mui datagrid component in my react project and want to add filters of '>' and '<'. I couldn't figure out from the documentation. Is there a prop in DataGrid for this?

P.S. I am new to material ui and am using the free version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.